# Usar el contenido de un archivo como valores de una variable BATCH

Tags: batch

Tengo un código pero sigo teniendo erroes y no se como solucionarlo.
Quiero hacer variables con el nombre del archivo e igualarlo a su tamaño de esta manera `f|archivo1.ext=tamaño` para esto tengo un archivo temporal en donde incluyo el nombre de los archivos y otro archivo temporal en donde incluyo el tamaño de los respectivos archivos.

```
setlocal
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('TYPE name.tmp') DO (
    FOR /F "Delims= " %%B in ('TYPE size.tmp') DO (
        set "f|%%~A=%%~B"
    )
)
```

Después en el mismo código entro a otro fichero para ver si existen archivos similares.
Si la variable no esta definida quiere decir que el archivo no se encuentra en el archivo temporal `name.txt`, pero si se encuentra el archivo lo que quiero hacer es ver los tamaños de los dos archivos.

```
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A in ('DIR /B *.*^|Findstr /VE ".tmp"^|Findstr /VE ".ini"') DO (
    if not defined f^|%%A (
        echo %%A
    ) else (
        setlocal Enabledelayedexpansion
            echo.%%A "%%~zA" "!f|%%A!"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Quiero que al final se pueda ver de la siguiente manera

```
documento1.txt "1948" "1948"
documento2.txt "120" "120"
```

Y el problema es que se ve de la siguiente manera

```
documento1.txt "1948" "120"
documento2.txt "120" "120"
```

Solo se toma el tamaño del último archivo.

Espero puedan ayudarme a solucionarlo